# Does a Perl module know where it is installed?

Tags: perl, module

I have started creating a Perl package that contains a default email template.

The MANIFEST looks something like:

```
SendMyEmail.pm
SendMyEmail/defualt_email.tt
```

Currently I know where the module (and the template) are - but does the module itself know where on disk it is?  So could the module find the default template without my help?

```
# This is what I would like to do.
package SendMyEmail;
sub new {
    my ($self, $template) = @_;
    $template ||= $dir_of_SendMyEmail .'/SendMyEmail/default_email.tt'; # ??
}
```

Is there a better way of including a templates text, or a better place to put the template?

Any references to CPAN modules that do something similar would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I'll vote to close the question. Cannot delete it because of upvoted answers.

Comment: Note that these two comments above are from a dupe question that has now been merged into this one, and as such are no longer accurate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each perl file has access to the variable `__FILE__` which tells it its full path. Something like this should do the trick:

```
my $DEFAULT_TEMPLATE;
BEGIN {
    $DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = __FILE__;
    $DEFAULT_TEMPLATE =~ s,\.pm$,/default_email.tt,;
}
```

Still, if all you want is to bundle 'data' files with your modules then take a look at [File::ShareDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ShareDir) which provides a way for doing that.

Answer (score 7):

Using %INC can be misleading in cases where the file does not exactly match the package name.  (This is an anti-pattern, but it does happen, sometimes for justifiable reasons.)  If you want to locate files, the handy [`__FILE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) token is your best bet.  Example module that can locate itself:

```
package Foo::Bar;

use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use File::Basename qw(dirname);

sub module_dir { abs_path(dirname(__FILE__)) }

1;
```

Usage:

```
use Foo::Bar;

print Foo::Bar->module_dir, "\n";
```

Comment: The example sub in the question is named "findmyself" and uses `__PACKAGE__`, so I think control of the module is a safe assumption.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `%INC` hash if module is already loaded. For example:

```
## load the module
use Data::Dumper;

## output full path to Data::Dumper module loaded
print $INC{'Data/Dumper.pm'};

## see which module was loaded (if you have multiple folders with same modules)
print Dumper(\%INC);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl records the file location in the `%INC` variable too. You can use that when `__FILE__` isn't available. See the documentation in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for the details.

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten to reflect what I learned in the comments:

- **Find Module's Path**

  ```
  package FooBar;

  use File::Spec;
  sub location  {
  return File::Spec->rel2abs( __FILE__);
  }
  ```
- **Where to put the template:**

  Since the template will most likely be editable, maybe even by someone working over the net, I strongly advise putting it into a directory where the "code" contained in the template cannot be executed.

  Imagine someone calling: `http://your.home.net/cgi-bin/default_email.tt`

Comment: FindBin will only give you the location of the perl script that was started (the .pl file) not the location of the file invoking FindBin.

Comment: Good point! Obviously I didn't read the question close enough!

Comment: Alas, __FILE__ doesn't return the full path either, 'only' the path relative to the script, it seems. The camel book (ancient copy) isn't specific either.

Comment: Using File::Spec's rel2abs() you can get the full path: File::Spec::rel2abs(__FILE__)

Comment: thanks potyl and mpeters, I've rewritten my answer according to your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__FILE__` token to get the name (including the path) of the current file. If you want to know the path to a different module (one that's already loaded) check the contents of the `%INC` hash.

Answer (score 1):

I use this bash alias to find the location of a module (e.g. to look at its implementation or to hack in some debugging print statements):

```
perlwhere() {
    perl -wle'eval "require $ARGV[0]" or die; ($mod = $ARGV[0]) =~ s|::|/|g; print $INC{"${mod}.pm"}' $1
}
```

```
$ perlwhere Test::More
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Test/More.pm
```