# How can I find out the file name of a require'd file in Perl?

Tags: perl

How do I find out the name of a file that was `require`'d, from within that file? I can look into `%INC` to find the names of all files that were loaded, but I am looking for something like `$0` that would serve as the key into `%INC`.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do that. I've been trying to think up a use case other than figuring out where the file is, or using it in a dynamically generated class or the like.

Comment: The file is a configuration file that is require'd in from a program, and I want the configuration file to pull in other configuration files located in the same directory.

You are right, in normal Perl "programming", you probably don't need this.

Comment: Do you have configuration files scattered in different locations? Why not `use lib "/my/conf/dir"` and avoid the chicanery?

Comment: For that I need to know the directory, which I get from %INC via __FILE__. Hence this question. :)  I don't want to hardcode the directory name.

Comment: @briandfoy Just found a use case: I'm in a PSGI application and want to `use lib` relative to the executable. `$0` points to the psgi server, twiggy in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a simple

```
my $filename=__FILE__;
print __FILE__;
```

should do ..

also look [here (does-a-perl-module-know-where-it-is-installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743137/does-a-perl-module-know-where-it-is-installed) and [here ( perldoc on Special-Literals )](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) for more ideas

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Bizarrely, you can't do $INC{__FILE__} because that looks up $INC{'__FILE__'}, so you need to go through an intermediate variable.

Comment: Peter: That's not entirely unexpected. $foo{bar} autoquotes, too. __FILE__ looks like any other identifier. Similar issues apply to constants.

Comment: @Peter Eisentraut: If you need to use `__FILE__` in a hash, use this `$INC{''.__FILE__}`. A little bit more typing, but it gets you there. All you need is one non-word char.

Comment: @tsee: Yeah but with constants, you can just throw `()` at the end to get them to evaluate: `MY_CONSTANT_PI()` (not in a string, though).

Comment: @Axeman: That's just for `use constant` style constants, which some people don't really like...

Comment: the perlish way of defeating bareword autoquoting is with the unary plus operator: `$INC{+__FILE__}` works.

Comment: @hobbs: I'mma gonna go gouge my eyes out now. *That's* inobvious code.